# How to handle sockets in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

I am using [Ratchett](http://socketo.me/) to create sockets on my web server with PHP.

Currently I have **A** - the server, **B** - a device looking for a change on a database(in **A**) and  **C** - a device making the change on the database(in **A**) with a `curl` request.

Currently when **C** makes the change I store the change in the database on **A**. Mean while **B** is checking every second with **A** through a socket whether there is an item is in the database by sending a request to **A** in which **A** returns a response. This is a waist of **B**s resources. I need a way for when **C** makes a change for the socket to update **B**.

This is the code for the socket:

```
<?php
namespace Notify;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

require "/NAS/notify/db.php";

class Note implements MessageComponentInterface { 
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $stack = array(); 
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from === $client) { //current client only
                $query = getNotifications($msg);
                if($query){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        array_push($stack, $row);
                        deleteNotification($row['id'], $msg);
                    }
                    $client->send(json_encode($stack));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Where `getNotifications()` gets the change in the database and `deleteNotification()` deletes it.

---

Ideas:

1. I have thought about storing the `$client` object in a database so that when **C** makes the change it can use `$client->send()` but I do not think that is possible?
2. I could have a `while(true)` loop with the `$query = getNotifications($msg);` code inside - awful for **A**.

Do you have any other ideas? Or ways to implement the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a publish-subscribe pattern where a client looking for updates to an object "X" subscribes to a topic and then have the server publish on that topic. Ratchet can handle this with WAMPv1: http://socketo.me/docs/wamp or you could use [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) which is [WAMPv2](http://wamp-proto.org/) built on top of ratchet.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any better examples of using wamp? I do not understand there DOCs in relation to my question.